# CSS Grid layout changes input width using a form

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to design a responsive form using CSS Grid but the input width changes to like 1 col when I start typing any information

This is the CSS:

```
.cftv_representante_form {
    background-color: rgb(82, 82, 82);
    color: #fff;
}
.cftv_representante_form {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: auto;
    grid-auto-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-areas: "h1" "p" "nome1" "nome2" "email1" "email2" "cpf1" "cpf2" "telefone1" "telefone2" "botao"
}
.cftv_representante_form p {
    padding: 5px 0 30px 0;
}
.cftv_representante_form input {
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
    width: 100% !important;  
    color: #000; 
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 540px) {
    .cftv_representante_form {
        display:grid;
        grid-auto-columns: auto 15px auto !important;
        grid-auto-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto !important;
        grid-template-areas: "h1 h1 h1" "p p p" "nome1 nome1 nome1" "nome2 nome2 nome2" "email1 email1 email1" "email2 email2 email2" "cpf1 . telefone1" "cpf2 . telefone2" "botao botao botao" !important;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
        <form method="get" action="cftv_captar.asp">
            <div class="artigo cftv_representante cftv_representante_form">

                    <h1 style="grid-area: h1">Seja um de nossos representantes:</h1>
                    <p style="grid-area: p"><i style="color:#a0c402;">Todos os campos abaixo são obrigatórios</i></p>
                    <label style="grid-area: nome1">Nome completo:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: nome2" type="text" name="txtNome" id="txtNome" placeholder="Nome Sobrenome" maxlength="100" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: email1">E-mail:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: email2" type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" placeholder="nome@dominio.com.br" maxlength="80" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: cpf1">CPF:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: cpf2" type="text" name="txtCPF" id="txtCPF" placeholder="___.___.___-__" maxlength="14" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: telefone1">Telefone celular:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: telefone2" type="text" name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" placeholder="(__)_____-____" maxlength="15" required />
                    <input style="grid-area: botao" class="cftv_btn_envia_representante" type="submit" value="Enviar">  

            </div>
        </form>
```

This is how it's displayed:

[image]

But then, when the cursor goes into the first input, this is what happens with the input width:

[image]

What happened to the first input happens to all the other inputs.

If I change the HTML for this one below, the problem doesn't happen but the layout also doesn't work with the grid as the CSS is applied to the `<div>` and not to the `<form>`:

```
<div class="artigo cftv_representante cftv_representante_form">
                <form method="get" action="cftv_captar.asp">
                    <h1 style="grid-area: h1">Seja um de nossos representantes:</h1>
                    <p style="grid-area: p"><i style="color:#a0c402;">Todos os campos abaixo são obrigatórios</i></p>
                    <label style="grid-area: nome1">Nome completo:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: nome2" type="text" name="txtNome" id="txtNome" placeholder="Nome Sobrenome" maxlength="100" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: email1">E-mail:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: email2" type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" placeholder="nome@dominio.com.br" maxlength="80" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: cpf1">CPF:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: cpf2" type="text" name="txtCPF" id="txtCPF" placeholder="___.___.___-__" maxlength="14" required />
                    <label style="grid-area: telefone1">Telefone celular:</label>
                    <input style="grid-area: telefone2" type="text" name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" placeholder="(__)_____-____" maxlength="15" required />
                    <input style="grid-area: botao" class="cftv_btn_envia_representante" type="submit" value="Enviar">  
                </form>
            </div>
```

I have tried to apply the CSS layout to the `<form>` and several other small attempts but with no success.

Do you guys know if there's any CSS characteristic I can apply to the `<form>` so it doesn't get in the way?

Comment: Using your code (with the first HTML block), I am not able to reproduce the problem on Chrome. The inputs *do not* collapse. https://jsfiddle.net/89qdxdaq/

Comment: I am also using Chrome but here it does happens

Comment: Chrome on mac OS High Sierra - No problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Resolved it by simply putting it inside div.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
<div class="artigo cftv_representante cftv_representante_form">
            <form method="get" action="cftv_captar.asp">
                <h1 style="grid-area: h1">Seja um de nossos representantes:</h1>
                <p style="grid-area: p"><i style="color:#a0c402;">Todos os campos abaixo são obrigatórios</i></p>
                <label style="grid-area: nome1">Nome completo:</label>
                <div id="nomeBox" style="grid-area: nome2"><input style= type="text" name="txtNome" id="txtNome" placeholder="Nome Sobrenome" maxlength="100" required /></div>
                <label style="grid-area: email1">E-mail:</label>
                <input style="grid-area: email2" type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" placeholder="nome@dominio.com.br" maxlength="80" required />
                <label style="grid-area: cpf1">CPF:</label>
                <input style="grid-area: cpf2" type="text" name="txtCPF" id="txtCPF" placeholder="___.___.___-__" maxlength="14" required />
                <label style="grid-area: telefone1">Telefone celular:</label>
                <input style="grid-area: telefone2" type="text" name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" placeholder="(__)_____-____" maxlength="15" required />
                <input style="grid-area: botao" class="cftv_btn_envia_representante" type="submit" value="Enviar">  
            </form>
        </div>
```